# Resetting git config

Tags: git

While trying to trouble shoot another problem, I entered this line of code: `git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400`. Now when I push git will compress objects, write objects, display the total, then pause for 30 seconds or more. I was hoping to reset the http.postBuffer but wasn't sure how.

Comment: See if this works: `git config --global --unset http.postBuffer`

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen awesome, thank you

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation of `git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config). You can also read its documentation in the comfort of your terminal window by typing `git help config`. Replace `config` with any other Git command to get help about it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To unset a global configuration setting in git you would run the following kind of command:

```
git config --global --unset X
```

where `X` is the name of the setting, so in your case you should be able to remove the setting by doing this:

```
git config --global --unset http.postBuffer
```

---

Also be aware that the global git settings are stored in a `.gitconfig` file in your "HOME" directory. This would similar to `C:\Users\<username>` on Windows and `~/` on *nix operating systems. This is just a normal text file so you could also find the offending setting in there and just edit it out.